# How to detect a click anywhere on a SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

How to detect a click on searchView?

I have tried using setOnClickListener, setOnSearchClickListener, setOnFocusChangedListener, but to no avail.

The problem seems to be only click on textbox. If I click anywhere outside of textbox onClickListener triggers, but not if click inside the textbox.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that I need to close a if user clicks anywhere. But I dont know how to handle the SearchView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to solve my problem.
It's a bit hackish, but it works. You have to get the editText from searchView and set OnClickListener to it

```
    int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
    editText.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Or more simply : `EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);`.

Comment: I have tried that, but for some reason it didn't work. The editText comes out null. I have no idea why...

Comment: Is there an interger value named `search_src_text` somewhere in your `R.java` file?

Comment: yes, if there wasn't the app would not compile in first place

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         searchView.setIconified(false);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"` to the SearchView tag in your layout XML.

Answer (score -1):

An answer from a similar question: [How to detect if SearchView is expanded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486194/how-to-detect-if-searchview-is-expanded)

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _ , hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        // searchView expanded
    } else {
        // searchView not expanded
    }
}
```