# How to detect if SearchView is expanded?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, searchview

I have the menu items like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.passenger, menu );
  searchItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search );
  searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView( searchItem );
  searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled( false );
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
}
```

I want to check if the searchView is expanded.

I tried `searchItem.isActionViewExpanded()` and `searchView.isHovered()` but none of them worked.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Where? Why don't you use listener?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try searchItem.isIconified()

> Returns the current iconified state of the SearchView.
>
> Returns
>
> true if the SearchView is currently iconified, false if the search field is fully visible.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#isIconified%28%29

Answer (score 20):

Try this, it will detect when the user clicks on the search icon:

In Kotlin:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _ , hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            // searchView expanded
        } else {
            // searchView not expanded
        }
    }
```

In Java :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // searchView expanded
        } else {
            // searchView not expanded
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: SearchView can be expanded and not having focus

Answer (score 18):

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do what you want when search view expended
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                //do what you want  searchview is not expanded
                return false;
            }
        });
```